# Return base class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, radix

How can i return data that is in base class form?

```
A aclass = new A();
B bclass = aclass.GetB();
```

does not work.

```
public class B
{
    protected string str1;
    protected string str2;
}

public class A:B
{
    public A()
    {
         base.str1 = "A";
         base.str2 = "B";
    }

    public B GetB()
    {
        return base;
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: A aclass = new A();
B bclass = aclass.GetB();

does not work

Comment: Whats wrong with simply using `B bclass = aclass;`? Every instance of `A` is also an instance of `B` because `A` is derived from `B`.

Comment: @petre what do you mean by "does not work". are you getting an error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`GetB()` is completely unnecessary. `B bclass = aclass;` is sufficient as `aclass` is already a `B`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm no C# expert, but `return this;` should work. I really don't see the point in doing this though.

Comment: No if i return

   this

it goes iteratively to infinity.

Comment: @petre "iteratively to infinity" What? So much "i".

Comment: @petre what goes iteratively to infinty here? Post the rest of your code.

Answer (score 3):

I strongy advise not to use the following code and instead change the behavior of your class but the answer is the following:

```
public B GetB()
{
    return this as B;
}
```

but instead writing a unique method for returning the object casted to the base class you may use the following;

```
public class B
{
    protected string str1;
    protected string str2;
}

public class A : B
{
    public A()
    {
        str1 = "A";
        str2 = "B";
    }
}
```

and you can use as the following;

```
A a = new A();
B b = a;
```

Comment: I have added the casting explicitly since OP seems not to have deep knowledge about c#.

Comment: @daryal That would be teaching him inappropriate usage of the type system.  The fact that he doesn't have a deep understanding only makes it that much more important you do it properly, so he will emulate proper behavior.

Comment: @daryal: Nevertheless it's unnecessary and may lead to wrong conclusions.