# How to call Linq Take() over base class IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I'm trying: `RandomBytes` generates random bytes (so, it's enumerable). `RandomNBytes` is the same but `N` random bytes (it extends `RandomBytes`). So, code is:

```
class RandomBytes : IEnumerable<byte>, IEnumerable {
    public IEnumerator<byte> GetEnumerator() {
        var rnd = new Random();
        while (true) {
            yield return (byte)rnd.Next(0, 255);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

class RandomNBytes : RandomBytes {
    readonly UInt64 Count;

    RandomNBytes (UInt64 count) {
        Count = count;
    }

    public new IEnumerator<byte> GetEnumerator() {
        return ((IEnumerable<byte>)base).Take(Count);
    }
}
```

But there is a problem with `base`, VC raises error: Use of keyword "base" is not valid in this context. How to call `Take()` over base-class enumerable?

Comment: use `this` instead of `base`.

Comment: `base` can only be used as a way of getting to a specific version of a member, it does not refer to "base version of this", you have to use `this` for all references to the *object instance*, which is what you're trying to do here. Unfortunately this doesn't mesh with your code all that well, since it will call the same `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: Super strange, `return this.Take(Count).GetEnumerator();` works

Comment: `this` (in this context) allows you to access methods (and properties etc) **or the object itself**. `base` is only to access methods (and properties etc).

Comment: @RandRandom yes, I will use it as generator, combinind with `Zip()` with another sequence (but finite)

Comment: You know you can use `random.NextBytes(array)` instead of making your own classes for this.

Comment: @Magnus but this pollute allocated array. I prefer generating over allocation to avoid memory eat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get Base Class Instance from a Derived Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243057/how-to-get-base-class-instance-from-a-derived-class)

Comment: @Paul-AG Did your `return this.Take(Count).GetEnumerator();` **really** work, or did it just compile? It still produces tons of data when I tested it. The reason is that the `IEnumerable` interface is implemented by the base class, and the `GetEnumerator` method of the descendant is declared with `new`, which doesn't implement the method of the interface.

Comment: I just tested it, it is compiled only! StackOverflowException is raising!

Comment: On the other hand, actually calling your new `GetEnumerator`, then calling `.MoveNext()` on the enumerator ends up with a stack overflow exception, as expected.

Comment: As I said, switching to `this` doesn't mesh with your request to append `.Take` as you actually need to call the base enumera**ble**, not the base enumera**tor**. Your only option the way I see it is to actually implement your descendant `GetEnumerator` properly, without using LINQ.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen you are super right. This variant works!

Comment: Here's an example - https://gist.github.com/lassevk/b78847a6cddde43a8cd4f783d5fb9160 - not able to write up a proper answer right now but anyone that wants to can just copy and rewrite that code and make it their own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
public class RandomBytes : IEnumerable<byte>, IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator<byte> GetEnumerator()
    {
        //used null, but could also drop the nullable and just pass ulong.MaxValue into the method
        return GetEnumerator(null);
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    //extracted the "main" method to a seperate method that takes a count
    protected IEnumerator<byte> GetEnumerator(ulong? count)
    {
        //use ulong.MaxValue when null gets passed, 
        //what ever you are doing with this code 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 iterations should be enough
        var c = count ?? ulong.MaxValue; 

        var rnd = new Random();
        for (ulong i = 0; i < c; i++)
            yield return (byte)rnd.Next(0, 255);
    }
}

public class RandomNBytes : RandomBytes
{
    readonly ulong Count;

    public RandomNBytes(ulong count)
    {
        Count = count;
    }

    public new IEnumerator<byte> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator(Count); //call the protected method
    }
}
```